# Java: Separate starting character from a string

Tags: java, android, string

How to get Starting alphabet from the string which contain numbers and other strings ?

Like have to separate the alphabets before the numbers starts.

```
String value1 = "test123123hj";
String value2 = "demo312342343dfs";
```

Output should be :

```
value1 = "test"
value2 ="demo"
```

Comment: `s.split("\\d+");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `split` method of string and pass in the regex to check the presence of digits.

```
"test123123hj".split("\\d+")[0]
```

This should give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@ChaitanyaWaikar's result is right. Try this.